# Material-UI: Set the style of a SelectField (or its underlying DropDownMenu)

Tags: material-ui

Trying to use a simple SelectField, and it *works* fine, but it looks terrible!

I'm using the default styles for MaterialUI components, and the standard theme.

The demo on the website (when clicked) looks like this:

[image]

However, mine looks like:

[image]

So, slightly different :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using some other stylesheet or reset?

Comment: Yeah -- normalize.css and some styles of my own.  However, it hasn't affected any other Material-UI component, just the menus.  I think I'll try starting from zero in a test project and see if I can track it down that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Matt it turns out that it is the [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) CSS reset that I'm using.

The important bit of code is:

```
/**
 * 1. Prevent a WebKit bug where (2) destroys native `audio` and `video`
 *    controls in Android 4.
 * 2. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 */

button,
html [type="button"], /* 1 */
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
}
```

Comment this section out and it works fine.